# Able to get collection, but not filtered data in production version of Slim app using Eloquent

Tags: eloquent, slim

I've been working on a Slim 2 and have just recently started deploying to a production server. Everything seems to be working okay so far. I'm able to log in so I know that I'm connecting to the database just fine. It recognized who I'm logged in as recognized what permissions I have as this user. I have another table with several entries. When I do...

```
$collection = collect($app->item->where('user_id', $userId)->get());
```

and then...

```
print_r($collection);
```

on the production server, I see the whole collection just like I do on the development server, but when I add...

```
$pack = $collection->where('status', 1);
```

and instead of printing the collection, try to print the pack like...

```
print_r($pack);
```

this message comes back...

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection Object ( [items:protected] => Array ( ) )
```

where on the development version I get the filtered collection as I would expect. How can I alter the code to work in both development and production environments?

Comment: Could it be you have no items in the collection where the status is 1 in production, but you do have some with a status of 1 in development?

Comment: Have you tried to chain the where function? Eg: $app->item->where('user_id', $userId)->where('status', 1)->get(); And make sure the database is having some rows with status = 1.

Comment: I have verified that there are items with a status of 1 in the production db and in the collection that comes back. I have tried to successfully chain the where('status', 1) when I make the collection which works, but I also need to further filter down where status = 1 and where status = 0 and I don't want to hit the db more than necessary.

Comment: What about for the specific user you're logged in as? Are there items with status = 1 for that user in production?

Comment: @quickshiftin I'm able to view the collection for that user, just not a filtered down collection made from that one and like I said above, when I chain the where's together it works as well.

Comment: In that case I'd recommend determining what the differences are between your production and development environments are. If the code works as expected in development, but not production, _something_ is causing that difference. Consider updating your development database to match your production database and try to reproduce the issue in development. From there you can use a debugger to determine where the discrepancy lies.

Comment: @quickshiftin I'm able to pull the collection for this user from the db in the production environment and development environment and I have verified that (aside from the creation/update dates) they are identical. My understanding is that the collection is just a multidimensional array and that doing the additional $collection->where() just filters against that array, not going back to the database. Am I right about that?

Answer (score 6):

Most likely you don't have records in the production database with a *status* of 1 and you do have records with a *status* of 1 in development.

Check the database directly in production to verify.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the collection only has strings in it or it will only match a string... this works!

```
$pack = $collection->where('status', '1');
```

Comment: Glad you found a solution, upvote from me. I suspect Slim is using `===` internally to compare the second argument to results from the database instead of `==`. Could find out by looking at the code... The big mystery though is how your code works in dev but not production without making the second argument a string.

Comment: @quickshiftin Above you suggested checking the structure of the db. Only difference I could find was that the local version was using InnoDB while the remote was using MyISAM. Not sure if that was the origin of the issue, but I have changed dev to match production.

Comment: I was talking about the values of the records, not the structure (schema) of the DB. Assumed the schema at least would be the same. Essentially when the same code works in dev but not prod, just need to eliminate the differences to determine where the issue lies. Still never got that questioned answered though. Why are you getting different results in both environments without the code change?

Answer (score 2):

Check your Eloquent version. Before 5.3 collections used strict comparison when using `where()` and to use loose you use `whereLoose()` but as of 5.3 `where()` is a loose comparison and `whereStrict()` is the strict method call.